# How can I get this code implemented with my ActionBar Tab setup?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, seekbar

I recently changed my application to have the action bar tabs to switch between Fragments. I coding I have done for the first fragment which is on the main activity is working fine, but on the second Tab it displays the items in its corresponding XML file but, none of my Java code seems to be working. I want 3 seek bars to change the number of a Text View, I had it working when I wasn't using Fragments, but just cant get it to work.

Do i have to put the code in a certain place of this file?

```
public class CountdownFragmentTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.countdown, container, false);

}
```

}

And this is what i want to add to this file:

```
SeekBar seekBar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    SeekBar seekBar2 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    SeekBar seekBar3 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
    final TextView seekBar1Value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbar1value);
    final TextView seekBar2Value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbar2value);
    final TextView seekBar3Value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbar3value);

    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar1, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            seekBar1Value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar2, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            seekBar2Value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    seekBar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar3, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            seekBar3Value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You keep saying that nothing is working, can you tell us WHAT is not working? Is it throwing an exception? Is it just not showing anything? Is it causing your phone to explode into a million little pieces?

Comment: I explained above that it displays but when moving the sliders the textview doesnt change its content, like it should before moving to using tabs and fragments.